# kubelet unable to get node status after kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler restarted

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kubernetes-networking, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler

My k8s `1.12.8` cluster (created via kops) has been running fine for 6+ months. Recently, something caused both `kube-scheduler` and `kube-controller-manager` on the master node to die and restart:

```
SyncLoop (PLEG): "kube-controller-manager-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal_kube-system(abc123)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"abc123", Type:"ContainerDied", Data:"def456"}
hostname for pod:"kube-controller-manager-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal" was longer than 63. Truncated hostname to :"kube-controller-manager-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.inter"
SyncLoop (PLEG): "kube-scheduler-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal_kube-system(hij678)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"hij678", Type:"ContainerDied", Data:"890klm"}
SyncLoop (PLEG): "kube-controller-manager-ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.internal_kube-system(abc123)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"abc123", Type:"ContainerStarted", Data:"def345"}
SyncLoop (container unhealthy): "kube-scheduler-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal_kube-system(hjk678)"
SyncLoop (PLEG): "kube-scheduler-ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal_kube-system(ghj567)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"ghj567", Type:"ContainerStarted", Data:"hjk768"}
```

Ever since `kube-scheduler` and `kube-controller-manager` restarted, kubelet is completely unable to get or update any node status:

```
Error updating node status, will retry: failed to patch status "{"status":{"$setElementOrder/conditions":[{"type":"NetworkUnavailable"},{"type":"OutOfDisk"},{"type":"MemoryPressure"},{"type":"DiskPressure"},{"type":"PIDPressure"},{"type":"Ready"}],"conditions":[{"lastHeartbeatTime":"2020-08-12T09:22:08Z","type":"OutOfDisk"},{"lastHeartbeatTime":"2020-08-12T09:22:08Z","type":"MemoryPressure"},{"lastHeartbeatTime":"2020-08-12T09:22:08Z","type":"DiskPressure"},{"lastHeartbeatTime":"2020-08-12T09:22:08Z","type":"PIDPressure"},{"lastHeartbeatTime":"2020-08-12T09:22:08Z","type":"Ready"}]}}" for node "ip-172-20-60-88.eu-west-2.compute.internal": Patch https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-172-20-60-88.eu-west-2.compute.internal/status?timeout=10s: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal": Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal?timeout=10s: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal": Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal?timeout=10s: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal": Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded
Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal": Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-x-x-x-x.z.compute.internal?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Unable to update node status: update node status exceeds retry count
```

The cluster is completely unable to perform any updates in this state.

- What can cause the master node to lose connectivity to nodes like
  this?
- Is the 2nd line in the first log output *'Truncated
  hostname..'* a potential source of the issue?
- How can I further
  diagnose what is actually causing the get/update node actions to
  fail?

Answer (score 0):

I remember kubernetes limits the hostname to less than 64 characters. Is there a case where hostname is updated this time?
If so it would be good to reconstruct the kubelet configuration using this documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/